# Misbehaving of stylus based notetaking programs (Xournal, Jarnal) after installing Ubuntu 12.10 in Surface Pro

Tags: 12.10, surface, stylus

Recently I installed **Ubuntu 12.10** in my **Surface Pro**, and everything works just fine out of the box. But note-taking programs like **Xournal, Jarnal** are misbehaving in a bad way.

In **xournal**, suddenly the screen gets filled with straight lines that I did not draw.

In **Jarnal**, it is even worse, the stylus draws all sorts of crazy curves while hovering over the screen (yes, the stylus does not even need to touch the screen!).

What is strange is that when I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in virtualbox (Windows 8 Host), they worked perfectly.

I will appreciate very much if anyone could give some suggestion on how to resolve this.

Comment: This has to do with the lack of support for the tablet's pen in the linuxwacom drivers. I get the same issue on MyPaint and other drawing software. Not sure there is a fix for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This happens as Ubuntu does not have palm block. So to use the stylus for taking notes, disable touch first. Also increase the threshold limit of the stylus to 60 (default 20). In terminal run:

`xinput disable 'Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer'`

`xinput set-prop "MICROSOFT SAM" "Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold" 60`

After you are done taking notes, enable the touch again by running:

`xinput enable 'Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer'`